# How to partition values into groups of 2 records?

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, partitioning, database-partitioning

What I'm trying to achieve is basically Col2. So for every 2 rows 1 label would be assigned. How can I do it in Oracle SQL?

```
Col1 Col2
20   1
21   1
22   2
23   2
24   3 
25   3
26   4
27   4
28   5
29   5
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is arithmetic and row_number():

```
select col1, 
       ceil(row_number() over (order by col1) / 2) as col2
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0ae30a09f72c3203db7bf556ddebc2f) is a db<>fiddle.